# angularjs - select dropdown has an extra option

Tags: angularjs, select

How can I remove the first empty < option > in the select drop down? I just want the first < option > to be the  "-Select-".

[image]

html

```
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Distance in KM
    <span  class="nullable">
      <select ng-model="myColor" >
       <option value="null">- Select -</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
      </select>
    </span><br/>
  </div>
```

script

```
angular.module('selectExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.myColor = '';
    }]);
```

Comment: that is because you initialize your myColor which does not exist in this select

Answer (score -1):

Use `ng-init` to initialize default blank value and also set blank value in `option` element:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="myColor = ''">
    Distance in KM
    <select ng-model="myColor">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Or since you are already initializing it in controller, just delete **null** from option.

Comment: I Just removed the value from null to blank. Thanks.